# C language. Declaration of the array, size of which is given by the macros #define

Tags: c, arrays, macros, declaration, c-preprocessor

I wonder why when I try to declare the array using `#define` I get errors from compiler, while using literal instead of the size allows me to do so.

#### some_name.h:

```
#define size 10;

int* waitingBench[size];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `;` from your definition. As you currently have it, this is equivillent to `int* waitingBench[10;];` which you know is incorrect.

Macro definitions are not C instructions, so they do not need to be terminated with a semi-colon (and they must not exceed one line unless a line continuation backslash is used, and they must not share the line with something else).

Comment: OMG!!! Thank you very much, I already spent a lot of time trying to figure out that is wrong. Thanks!!))

Answer (score 7):

What you have will be pre-processed to:

```
int* waitingBench[10;];
//                  ^ notice this guy!
```

Remove the semicolon from the `#define`.

(And `size` is a really bad identifier to `#define`.)

Comment: +2 for the note about `size` :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove ";" in the end:

```
#define size 10
```